# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 485734, expected page length 4..256, got 1769366861 [1.4.199/6]Jenkins errors

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Out of a sudden my Jenkins started lagging. Every short hang comes with an error message that refers to the same corrupted chunk.

```
05-Jan-2021 12:16:39.022 WARNING [Handling POST /jenkins/ajaxExecutors from 127.0.0.1 : http-nio-8181-exec-2] hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleException Caught unhandled exception with ID 917626d3-7f6f-49ab-bb23-e3ea74dd9497
        javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:200)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:169)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
...skipping...
                        at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:259)
                        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollbackInternal(JdbcConnection.java:1603)
                        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:563)
                        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.close(ProxyConnection.java:257)
                        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.maven.dao.PipelineMavenPluginH2Dao.isEnoughProductionGradeForTheWorkload(PipelineMavenPluginH2Dao.java:69)
                        ... 155 more
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 485734, expected page length 4..256, got 1769366861 [1.4.199/6]
                        at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:883)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readBufferForPage(MVStore.java:1055)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.visit(MVStore.java:1606)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.Page.readChildrenPositions(Page.java:274)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.visit(MVStore.java:1607)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.visit(MVStore.java:1571)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.visit(MVStore.java:1603)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.inspectVersion(MVStore.java:1513)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1458)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.freeUnusedChunks(MVStore.java:1407)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.freeUnusedIfNeeded(MVStore.java:1400)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1208)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1190)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.tryCommit(MVStore.java:1135)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2763)
                        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:3123)
        Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 485734, expected page length 4..256, got 1769366861 [1.4.199/6]]
```

A simple restart did not help so I tried to recover the h2 database but this end up with:

```
java -cp h2-1.4.199.jar org.h2.tools.Recover 
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeNanos out of range 208648290000104
```

The system did not crash and there were no updates installed when the issue started.

So I'm running out of ideas. Has anybody seen / solved this type of error in the past?

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by the pipeline maven plugin. After disabling it the performance was back to normal.